# Genymotion is crashing when I search my current location but when I run the same app in my mobile it is sucessfully running

Tags: android, google-maps, genymotion

```
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemap/com.example.googlemap.LocationSearch}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.example.googlemap.LocationSearch.onCreate(LocationSearch.java:95)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-20 07:50:39.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     ... 11 more
```

and Genymotion is showing error on:

```
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Even my Genymotion GPS location is ON and set on my current location
and it is running fine on my mobile device.

Comment: Are you using Google Location Services ? Genymotion doesn't bundle them. In that case you should flash'em into the emulator

Comment: yes I am using Google Location Services and it is still showing the same error. Thank you for the reply

Comment: Ok, did you manually flash gapps inside Genymotion?

Comment: Ok thank you I will try to implement this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best practice if you use real device for camera or location based apps.As real devices have different camera features that you can not access on emulator.Same is the case with location based apps that you can not have real locations on emulator and more of that Google keep updating map apis for real devices.

Comment: Genymotion emulators, which the OP asked about, do support GPS functionality within your app.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are using Google Location Services but you don't have Gapps inside the Genymotion emulator!

Try to follow [this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) in order to flash'em inside the Genymotion ROM.